# JNI & Multi Threads

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a multi threaded JAVA app that uses a shared c lib. What will happen to this library if I'l access it from different threads?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This absolutely depends on the C library. If the function does not store any state (e.g. just computes some result and only uses local variables on stack ) it will be safe to use it from multiple Threads. Otherwise you have to take care that the state ist stored separately for each thread, e.g. by using malloc and returning a handle for further calls, so that following calls will reuse the state in the malloced memory block.

If I dont know the internals of the code, I prefer building a small C application and calling it using Runtime.exec, but this is useful only if the C function is doing enough work to justify the exec overhead.